# Access google cloud bucket using simple API

Tags: api, google-cloud-storage

How to create a new bucket in the google cloud using simple API key with dot net or MSXML2.XMLHTTP or HttpWebRequest.

please provide any sample or example..

i am new to google cloud, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Cloud Storage JSON API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/) would be your best bet to manage your data in the Cloud Storage via a programmatic API.

Check out the [How To Guides](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos).

You can use an API Key for ensure that the authorized client is making those calls. The mechanism for generating the API Key is mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing). Your application can append the query parameter key=yourAPIKey to all request URLs.

Comment: Simple upload is okay for me but it has to be Authorization, is that correct. When i suppose to create a simple api key, then there is no need to authorization.

Comment: I have created API key for browser and append in the url like below. https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=causal-tracker-594&key=AIzaSyCCuFhBk7esMsmvi1aDFpAHPYlLzs but got some error {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}

Comment: Is it possible without Authorization we can upload and download docs using API.

Comment: If you visit your Google Project in your Developers Console, please ensure that you see Google Cloud Storage API as ON (Enabled) in the list of APIs. The error indicates that.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to upload/download docs with any sort of security. If you still want to do that, you might have to write your own Server layer that takes it the data and then behind the scenes, it can talk to the underlying Storage mechanism via the key, etc.

Comment: its a intranet site only, so it's ok for without any security. Did you find any sample or example.

Comment: There are samples / api examples in the documentation : https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries. Pls check.